# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: " Predicting When This Error Will Happen

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I'm working alongside a data collection application, essentially it is a black box to me.

In the config file I can set the heap size Xmx500MB for example. The application is built in a way that I can dynamically add more factory lines (via a UI) for it to record data.

Originally it collected data for one line with a heap of 500MB. After adding the second line it ended up getting "Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" and after increasing the memory to 1300MB it worked again. I will have to add more lines in the future.

Monitoring the process in task-manager it uses the full space allocated.

How can I determine the min amount of memory needed before this error occurs?

Basically determine how much memory does a new line need.

I don't want to add a new line and the entire system suddenly breaks due to this error.

Comment: If you are concerned with this happening in Production, you can perhaps try it in a test environment first.

Comment: In the commercial web systems I work on we never use a heap of less that 2G . Usually much higher.   What is your constraint?

Comment: @Rahul I wish I had a test environment but I don't know of a way to simulate it. At the very least I would need extra licensing to create the test environment and the customer wouldn't foot the bill for it. Its very much wing it as we go unfortunately.

Comment: @Totoro, as far as I can tell this error is the bottle neck atm. It's a 32 bit service so I can't allocate more memory then it can address. The technician I spoke to said using above 1500mb memory can result in some unexpected behaviors. I'm not sure what those are. I'm stuck as a middle man setting it up for the end user.

EDIT: To add its a VM running on a server so physically is not the bottle neck, ram/cpu/storage to spare.

Comment: I can understand your situation but I think your best bet is to get a test environment. Even to determine an approximate memory for each new line, you will have to run tests. I think this is a genuine issue and client should understand it. I can't imagine doing such a thing in Production without testing it. Good luck!